# How do I install scitools module on Python3 with Anaconda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, scitools

I need to install the scitools module in Anaconda. The commands

```
conda install scitools
conda install --channel johannr scitools
conda install -c asmeurer scitools
```

don't work. I'm using Python 3 on Windows 10. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you see any error messages? Please add them to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The packages you are trying to install are only available for linux and osx, you can try with this one:

```
conda install -c krisvanneste scitools_no_easyviz
```

Though as the name states it seems to not have support for EasyViz